# The official Inno Setup code to change Next button to Install with DisableReadyPage directive does not work

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using the code from:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablereadypage

It should change the *Next* button caption to *Install* when the "Ready" page is disabled using `DisableReadyPage` directive.

```pascal
[Setup]
DisableReadyPage=yes

[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectProgramGroup then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall)
  else
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
end;
```

But it does not change *Next* button caption.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As the description of the code says:

> For example, if the new last pre-installation wizard page is the **Select Program Group page**: ...

In your case the last pre-installation page is not *Select Program Group* page. It's the *Select Destination Location* page. Probably because you have `DisableProgramGroupPage` set to `no`, or you have set it to `auto` and you are upgrading (the application is installed already).

If you have the `DisableProgramGroupPage` set to `no`, the solution is simple, as the *Select Destination Location* page is always the last. Just replace the `wpSelectProgramGroup` with `wpSelectDir`.

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall)
  else
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
end;
```

With `auto` (the default), you do not get any of *Select Program Group* and *Select Destination Location* on upgrade, but you get the *Ready to Install* even with `DisableProgramGroupPage` (as there would not be any other page before installation). You can use that fact to use *Install* both for *Select Program Group* page (for fresh installs) and *Ready to Install* (for upgrades).

Another issue with their code is that you should get a *Finish* button on the "Finished" page (`wpFinished`). What their code does not care for.

The complete solution is:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // On fresh install the last pre-install page is "Select Program Group".
  // On upgrade the last pre-install page is "Read to Install"
  // (forced even with DisableReadyPage)
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectProgramGroup) or (CurPageID = wpReady) then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall)
  // On the Finished page, use "Finish" caption.
  else if (CurPageID = wpFinished) then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish)
  // On all other pages, use "Next" caption.
  else
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
end;
```

Had you have other pages, like *Tasks* page, you would have to alter the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows the `wpSelectDir` page while in your code you change the button of the `wpSelectProgramGroup` page.